# Image node not render properly on Vuzix M100

Tags: kudan

I fork your [sample code](https://github.com/kudan-eu/Simple-Samples-Android) to track my usb-stick, as this :

```
// Initialise image trackable
ARImageTrackable trackable = new ARImageTrackable("Usb");
trackable.loadFromAsset("usb.jpg");

// Get instance of image tracker manager
ARImageTracker trackableManager = ARImageTracker.getInstance();

// Add image trackable to image tracker manager
trackableManager.addTrackable(trackable);

// Initialise image node
ARImageNode imageNode = new ARImageNode("eyebrow.png");

// Add image node to image trackable
trackable.getWorld().addChild(imageNode);
```

It works great on Nexus7.

[image]

I try same app on [Vuzix M100](https://www.vuzix.com/Products/m100-smart-glasses), my marker is detected, but `ImageNode` (eyebrow) is not render properly (black image):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ARLightMaterial material = new ARLightMaterial();
material.setTexture(texture2D);
material.setAmbient(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
```

Comment: Sorry but I move on a new project since few months so I can't test that. I don't have Vuxy M100